# copy and pasting to a protected excel worksheet

Tags: copy-paste

I am running microsoft excel 2007 and have question about the copy and pasting function.  I want to know if it is possible to copy and paste from an unprotected worksheet to a worksheet that is protected and if so how?   Thank  You J

Answer (score 0):

Windows will copy the data to the clipboard from either Excel worksheet, but you will not be able to save any changes you make in the protected worksheet.

Comment: I am able to copy a row from the unprotected sheet but when i go to paste it on the protected sheet it says I have to uprotect the sheet.  I have that sheet protected so the users don't change the formulas in certain cells.  I dont want the users to unprotect the sheet because there would be chance the formulas could get lost or erased.  Any suggestions?

Comment: OH! I know what would work for you: With your Excel Spreadsheet open and a **region** selected that you want to allow access to, press (at the same time) CTRL+1 to bring up the `Format Cells` tool. Select the tab called `Protection` and **uncheck** the `Locked` option.

Comment: This will allow your users to make changes only to that part of your worksheet. ...alternately, you could *unlock* the entire form (CTRL+A to select the whole worksheet), then go back and only select the areas you want to protect, go in and *lock* those.